# reddit get_comments action, can someone clarify what is going on here?

Tags: python, pylons, reddit

I'm trying to understand reddit's source, and I am looking at the get_comments action method of front.py

This is the action that displays a story:

http://code.reddit.com/browser/r2/r2/controllers/front.py#L139

Specifically, what is the top part of the method doing where there is a @Validate marker?

And on the bottom near the return, it is sending objects to the view page.

Which viewpage is being called here?

```
211 res = LinkInfoPage(link = article, comment = comment,
212                            content = displayPane,
213                            subtitle = _("comments"),
214                            nav_menus = [CommentSortMenu(default = sort),
215                                         NumCommentsMenu(article.num_comments,
216                                                         default=num_comments)],
217                            infotext = infotext).render()
218         return res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically, what is the top part of the method doing where there is a @Validate marker?

@validate is validation decorator, used to validate and process parameters from request.
You can see its sources at http code.reddit.com/browser/r2/r2/controllers/validator/validator.py#L129

> And on the bottom near the return, it is sending objects to the view page.
>   Which viewpage is being called here?

It does not use 'view page', it uses widgets there. [LinkInfoPage](http://code.reddit.com/browser/r2/r2/lib/pages/pages.py#L717) which contains PaneStack (http code.reddit.com/browser/r2/r2/lib/pages/pages.py#L1317)

So res = LinkInfoPage(...).render() is already generated html, in Pylons response form. It recursively calls .render() on underlying widgets.

P.S. you need to add :// to links, since it does not let to post more than one link.